# Android: How to read Digital Signature Certificates from a secured USB token

Tags: android, cryptography, usb, spongycastle

I have a requirement of reading the certificates that are installed on a USB token which is connected to the android device (Phone/tablet). The USB dongle also has associated public and private keys with it.

For this, Should I use UsbInterface, UsbConnections to read it as we normally do. If yes, Then how should I check for the PIN(Usb token is secured with a PIN). If not, what are the other ways??

I have read that Gemalto is providing stuffs like this but they are supporting only their USB tokens and they are closed source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask the vendor this question. There are many devices out there, and probably multiple methods of handling PIN entry. Without the used protocols it would be hard to answer this.

Comment: Is that not any universal method or protocol which works irrespective of vendor. Because I have seen this in a PC environment. They are using PKCS11 and bouncy castle to read it. in windows environment they are just calling like ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
    ks.load(null, null); and in MAC and Unix they are calling other providers.